# Visual Studio C++: Refactoring between member and non-member functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a library, and I need to refactor a class X such that every call of the form:

```
f(x); //Non-member function
```

is subsituted with:

```
x.f(); //Member function
```

where f is a fixed method (same name in all the code) but x is an instance of type X, and as such will change.

Is there an wasy way to do a globl find and replace which would take care of such conversions?

Just in case, also knowing how to go from the member to the non-member case would be interesting :)

Thank you!

Comment: A global find and replace seems like it would solve this problem just fine. I can't tell from your question if you're asking *how* you could use that, or just if there is a *better* way of doing so. Unfortunately, Visual Studio doesn't have a lot of built-in refactoring support for C++.

Comment: But how would find and replace cope with both (say) f(x1); and f(x2); ? Clearly instances of X will have different names in my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find and Replace, using regular expressions and tagged groups.

Then you can replace `f\({:i}\)` with `\1.f()` and `f\(\*{:i}\)` with `\1->f()`

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. But if I change the find condition to f\\({:i}\\) it does.

Comment: Ah. Forgot to escape the brackets. You got the idea, though.

Comment: Could you please edit the reply which I accepted to include this :) If I run the search for the form f(*x) that will convert to x->f() before I have everything needed.

Answer (score 3):

Use the compiler, luke.

Since I cannot image how this could be done via textual replacement, and I very much doubt you have a refactoring tool available that does it[*] for you:

Simply change your class definition accordingly, so that the previous function is no longer available. Then let your compiler tell you where you need to replace the calls to a no-longer-existing function.

<sub>[*] : Actually, I doubt there's any refactoring tool for C++ available that is able to achieve this.</sub>

Comment: Yup, I agree. This is much simpler than combining regular expressions with global find-and-replace. Also much less error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

Can't imagine so, not without a *very* advanced refactoring plugin/addon. It's even a little more complicated than you'd expect at first, because you'd also want to change any calls like `x->f()` into `f(*x)`. Let's not even get into the situation where you have method pointers...

Comment: No method pointers in my case (but thanks for pointing this out, I did not think about it!). So the only two possible situations are f(x); and f(*x); and 95% is just f(x);